# mysql installation issue - Ubuntu 18.04 bionic

Tags: apt, server, package-management, mysql

On **logging in** to MySQL, I get the warning:

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I read on a page that this is due to mysql-server not being  installed: 
While **reinstalling** it

```
~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server
[sudo] password for krd: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

mysql **status** says :

```
~$ service mysql status
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Tried installing mysqll completely and reistalled again but still the same issue. I get the below shown mysql-server-5.7 issue while installing any other software aswell , but the system fails while installing it.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not going to be installed
 xterm : Depends: libutempter0 (>= 1.1.5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 0):

The socket error usually points to the service not being started, and the error you got later ( `inactive (dead)` ) also points to that direction.

The most probably cause is an invalid option in your configuration file (as indicated by `Reason: Invalid argument`).

Try to backup `/etc/my.cnf` via

`mv /etc/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf.bak`

and then restart the service via

`systemctl restart mysql`

If that works, then move back the config file and restart the service after commenting lines one by one until you figure out which one causes the break.

Comment: I tried the said process but still getting issue

                                      $~ systemctl restart mysql
Failed to restart mysql.service: Unit mysql.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status mysql.service' for details.

:~ systemctl status mysql.service
<E2> mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)